# Align the last li at the bottom of the container

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I can't figure out how I can align the last `<li>` element at the bottom of the container. The problem I find is that due to `column-count` and `column-fill`, the content automatically adapts to the columns preventing me from positioning the last element as I want. I tried using `padding-top`, `margin-top` and `line-height` but the result is always the same. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```css
* { font-family: Sans-serif }
.table1 { border: 1px solid red }

.table2 { border: 1px solid red }

.title-list { column-count: 2 }

.title-list li { margin-bottom: 10px }

.title,
.title:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cae3f7;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black
}

.more1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -15px
}
.more2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -15px;
  padding-top: 30px
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p><b>I want to align the last link at the bottom of the div</b></p>
  <div class="table1">
    <ol class="title-list">
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the first title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the second title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the third title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the fourth title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the fifth title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the sixth title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the seventh title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm eighth title </a></li>
      <li class="more1"><a href="#">Show me more >>></a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <p><b>But when I do this the columns change </b></p>
  <div class="table2">
    <ol class="title-list">
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the first title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the second title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the third title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the fourth title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the fifth title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the sixth title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the seventh title</a></li>
      <li><a class="title" href="#">I'm the eighth title </a></li>
      <li class="more2"><a href="#">Show me more >>></a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted (or as a stack snippet, when appropriate), and not just dumped onto an external site.

Comment: Sorry, better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/* the container */
.table-1 {
  position: relative;
}

li:last-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```